# How to show only particular number of data and hide remaining with more link

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I want to show notes of the user on the page but i just want to show only first 200 characters and after this there is a  link of more to navigate the user on the another page.
I completed that more link part but  I don't know about how to show only 200 characters and hide remaining with link.

Comment: You can create your own implementation of this . If you are using a dynamic server script like PHP, strip the text and put a read more  On click, show further text using Javascript.  Or you can check a sample using jquery only. read this : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/

Comment: thanks... this link is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract first 200 characters from the text and display it in div

```
var smallcontent = divContent.substr(0, 200) + "..";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmpbehf1/1/